# how to route pagination next page in uri->segment(1) eg (example.com/1)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have pagination in frontend index page `example.com` when I click page two of pagination I want to load page like eg `example.com/1`.

```
<?php 

function index()
{
    $e = $this->employer_model->count_jobs_with_employer();
    //print_r($e) ;
    $config['base_url'] = $this->config->site_url(); //set the base url for pagination
    $config['total_rows'] = $e; //total rows
    $config['per_page'] = '10'; //the number of per page for pagination
    $config['uri_segment'] = 1; //see from base_url. 3 for this case        
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); //initialize pagination

    $page  = ($this->uri->segment(1)) ? $this->uri->segment(1) : 0;

    $joblist['listemp'] = $this->employer_model->employerbyjob($config['per_page'], $page); 
    foreach($joblist['listemp'] as $emp)
    {
        $joblist['jobs'][$emp->u_id] =   $this->employer_model->get_ByTbl_Col('employer_post_job', 'e_id', $emp->u_id,'dead_line', date('Y-m-d'));  
    }

    $c['job_list'] = $this->load->view('front/blocks/employer/job_list', $joblist, TRUE);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you format your code so it becomes readable.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are looking for and please format your code

Comment: What is `$this`? Where is the rest of your class?

Comment: @putvande `$this` refer to the Codeigniter "superobject"; code is likely a Controller here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

**application/config/routes.php:**

```
//default routes:
$route['default_controller'] = "yourcontroller";
$route['404_override'] = '';

// your custom route:
$route['(:num)'] = "yourcontroller/index/$1";
```

**application/controllers/Yourcontroller.php**

```
function index($page = null)
{

}
```

Comment: big big thank u Damien Pirsy it really work one of my great headache off

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider marking it as accepted using the thick mark under the vote count. If you need additional help don't hesitate

Comment: doesn't he need _remap()? for index parameters?